# Alias a Virtual Directory or Application as Root on IIS 7

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, alias, virtual-directory

Our current IIS setup as two applications running on different paths at (for example) http://server/sub-a and http://server/sub-b. I want to alias http://server/sub-a as root so that just going to http://server/ will bring up the contents of sub-a. The problem I face is that when I initially set up a ReverseProxy it negatively affected http://server/sub-b. I know this is a fairly common problem- how have you solved it? 99.9% of my experience is with Apache, so I feel a tad lost in the GUI world of IIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a dedicated server then setup 2 separate sites pointing directly to the sub-a or sub-b folder.  Set the specific bindings on each site.

If you need to share them under a single site then here's the solution to [host multiple domains under one site](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/01/26/iis-url-rewrite-hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-site.aspx)

Comment: It's not that we need different domains from the same server, we actually want one to be the default 'root' page of the server, while not interrupting the use of the second app running on the server. The blog post you linked to does seem to hold the answer- I'll try implementing some of the ideas and let you know. The nice thing is we already have Rewrite 2.0 installed.

Comment: I don't fully see the big picture of your configuration so forgive me if I'm off, but what you can do is point the root of your site to /sub-a, and create a virtual directory called sub-b that points to the sub-b folder on disk.  That will make sub-a primary and root, while sub-b will works by http://server/sub-b.  URL Rewrite is great, but you may not need it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is change the 'alias' of your application in IIS you would think you could do this by selecting the parent (usually 'Default') and then going 'View applications' and then 'advanced settings', but as posted here, the IIS manager front end does *not allow you* to make this sort of change, see this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687057/renaming-applications-in-iis-7-0

However, as posted there, you can edit the configuration manually:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/150/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis-7/#Configuration

... you would not be alone, if you thought this was one of less-than-helpful things about the IIS configuration utility.